# Unable to create table in DynamoDB with billing mode set to PAY_PER_REQUEST

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am currently creating a table in DynamoDB using the AWS cli. The command I'm using is

```
aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://.feature_promotions-dynamodb.json  --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

Based on the docs for `create-table`, I should be able to set the billing-mode to `PAY_PER_REQUEST` without having to set the provisioned throughput, but every time run the command I get back the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: No provisioned throughput specified for the table
```

I upgraded `awscli` yesterday to

```
aws-cli/1.16.90 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/18.2.0 botocore/1.12.80
```

Other than that, I'm out of ideas on how to fix it. My workaround currently is to just create the table with a provisioned throughput and then go to the console to change it, but this seems unnecessary. Ultimately I'd like to be able to run this command in a bash script without having to later fix the table settings in the AWS console.

Below is the JSON file I load in the `create-table` command. `"BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST"` attribute and value are set after `"AttributeDefinition"` and I would expect this to work without any error. If I remove the billing mode line, and add the following attribute to the file

```
"ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
```

it creates the table without any errors.

```
{
  "TableName": "dev.feature_promotions",
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "display_title",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "end_date",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "partner_id",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "start_date",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "view_scope_id",
      "AttributeType": "N"
    }
  ],
  "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "id",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
    {
      "IndexName": "start_date-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "start_date",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "IndexName": "display_title-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "display_title",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "IndexName": "end_date-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "end_date",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "IndexName": "partner_id-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "partner_id",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "IndexName": "view_scope_id-index",
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "view_scope_id",
          "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }
      ],
      "Projection": {
        "ProjectionType": "ALL"
      },
      "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "StreamSpecification": {
    "StreamEnabled": true,
    "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
  },
  "SSESpecification": {
    "Enabled": true,
    "SSEType": "AES256",
    "KMSMasterKeyId": ""
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can only use one of `"BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST"` or `ProvisionedThroughput` on a table or GSI. You need to remove `ProvisionedThroughput` on any on-demand resources.

EDIT: To be clear, you can't use `ProvisionedThroughput` on the indexes of a table that is on-demand. To fix this, just remove all instances of `ProvisionedThroughput`. Your indexes will then also be on-demand.

Comment: After removing the **ProvisionedThroughput** , getting this error `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTable operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: ReadCapacityUnits and WriteCapacityUnits must both be specified when BillingMode is PROVISIONED`

Comment: I have the same issue, although I can't reproduce it in another repo...